# RegEx - inverse file match

Tags: regex

I am trying to build an exclude regex statement.  I need to exclude all non-zip files that do not contain the word "hit".

I have built an expression which matches the files I do want, but I need the inverse to match all other files for exclusion.

Example file list:

```
c:\myFolder\hit_1234.zip 
c:\myFolder\hit_1235.zip 
c:\myFolder\hit.txt 
c:\myFolder\otherfile.zip 
c:\myFolder\otherfile.txt 
c:\myFolder\hit_1236.zip
```

Expression which is matching the files I want:

```
.*hit.*\.zip
```

The end result would match all of these files so I can exclude them:

```
c:\myFolder\hit.txt
c:\myFolder\otherfile.zip 
c:\myFolder\otherfile.txt
```

Comment: Why don't you just invert the sense of the code that's performing the match? So instead of `if match(regexp, filename)` you use `if not match(regexp, filename)`

Comment: If you really have to do it just in the regexp, put your regexp in a negative lookahead.

Comment: The program I am using has regex support that only allows me to define exclusions unfortunately.  This is not custom code but rather just a vendor application I am working with.  I feel like a negative lookahead is the correct response but I have been unable to successfully write that logic which is why I am asking for help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take your regexp and put it inside `(?!...)` to make it a negative lookahead. You also need to anchor it so it tries to match the whole string (and fails if it includes the lookahead). So it's

```
^(?!.*hit.*\.zip).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/NG3AMH/1)